# Comment traduire "ground term" ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie, mathématiques

J'ai l'habitude de traduire *ground term* (en logique) comme *terme clos*. Or, selon [ce site](https://www.classle.net/faq/what-ground-term#), il y a une subtile différence entre *ground term* et *closed term*:

> In mathematical logic, a ground term of a formal system is a term that does not contain any variables at all, and a closed term is a term that has no free variables.

La seule traduction que j'ai trouvée qui distinguait les deux était *terme sur terre*, mais elle me sonne très étrange. Y a-t-il une autre traduction plus adaptée ?

Ou sinon, cela ne me gênerait pas d'en inventer une, mais dans ce cas, est-ce que le *ground* de *ground term* vient étymologiquement de *terre*, ou plutôt du participe passé de *grind*? Car une autre traduction telle que *terme moulu*, *terme haché*, ou similaire, me semblerait plus adaptée.

**Edit**: Le *ground* me fait aussi penser à *to be grounded*, quand les parents interdisent leurs enfants de sortir, ou quand des avions sont interdits de voler. Du coup, *terme ancré* ou *terme étayé* me semblent des possibilités, mais je ne vois aucune référence à ces deux variantes.

Comment: il y a bien "la masse"... en physique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On traduit généralement par *terme clos*, *formule close*, etc. dans tous les cas (que ce soit *ground* ou *closed*).

Voir par exemple les définitions pour le [Calcul des prédicats](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcul_des_pr%C3%A9dicats) ou le [Lambda calcul](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calcul).

Les définitions peuvent parfois paraître ambiguës, mais  lorsqu'on recense les variables d'un terme ou d'une formule, on ne s’intéresse jamais aux variables liées. Faire une différence entre *ground* et *closed* n'est donc pas très utile. On parlerait plutôt de formule sans quantificateur (ou de terme sans lieur) dans le cas où on ne veut aucune variable liée.

Il me semble aussi avoir déjà entendu *terme de base* pour *ground term*, mais c'est quand même très ambigu.

Answer (score 0):

Tout à fait fantaisiste :

> Terme invariant
>
> Terme stable

**EDIT** *après commentaire*

> Terme invariable
>
> Terme sans variable

Comment: *Terme invariant* est un peu ambigu, vu qu'il y a déjà en logique des "invariants". *Terme stable* me semble plus intéressant.

Answer (score 0):

C'est en effet une expression qui n'est pas simple à traduire. Il y a d'autres possibilités : (1) *terme sans variables* ; (2) *terme d'ordre 0* ; (3) *terme élémentaire*. L'option (1) est claire, mais un peu lourde ; la (2) s'oppose à "*terme de premier ordre*" (*first-order term*) ; mais la (3) est la plus simple et a le mérite de correspondre au fait qu'un tel terme dénote un élement unique (contrairement au terme de premier ordre qui dénote l'ensemble de toutes ses instances).